# Build Invoice reference on insert

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, insert, entity, listener

I'm working on an invoice project. One of my Invoice entity field is invoice_number, which is supposed to match this pattern :

```
F<YYYYMM><INCREMENT>
```

where YYYYMM is the current Year and Month and INCREMENT is an integer incremented on every invoice, and resetted to 1 every first invoice of the month. I'd like to be able to build that whole field when the entity is inserted in the database, but I dont find any way to listen to the entity insertion. Doctrine has some callbacks called prePersist, postPersist, bu they would trigger on every persist, not only on Insertion. And i dont want to rebuild that field on every persist.
One other way would be to create a custom method in my Entity, I would call "buildReference()" and I would call it after persisting my entity for DB insertion, but it seems I can't access the repository from inside an entity. So I can't retrieve the last increment saved, or things like that.

Any advice about how to achieve what I'm willing to do would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`prePersist` is only called on insert.

`preUpdate` is called on every update.

Even if it wasn't that way you could check whether the invoice number has already been set like..

```
if (null !== $invoice->getInvoiceNumber()) {
   return;
}

$calculator->generateInvoiceNumber($invoice);
```